# Adding a highscore list to a textbox VB2010

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

Hey everyone I'm working on a old school runescape client. I want to display the highscores in some way. I have got them to successfully display them in a textbox. Only problem is it looks like this :

[image]

... all jumbled together.
Here is the code to display in the textbox2 :

```
TextBox2.Text = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("contentHiscores").InnerText
```

how could i fix them getting jumbled

here is the highscore url: http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=iCapxer

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple:

```
dim variable As String = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("contentHiscores").InnerText
listbox1.Items.Add(variable)
```